# Sending to Mailchimp list using Mandrill SMTP

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I want to send an email out to a particular Mailchimp list by sending an email.  Mailchimp makes you review after sending the email, or to respond to an email to get it to send.

I was told that this is possible using the Mandrill integration, but I don't understand how I specify the Mailchimp list that it will be sent to.  Or even how to send an email using Mandrill that will be sent by Mailchimp.

Is that done through custom headers?  Is there an example of this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? Trying to solve this myself right now.